# attribute naming, tuple vs multiple names

Tags: python, class, attributes, naming-conventions

I was thinking about parts of my class api's and one thing that came up was the following:
Should I use a tuple/list of equal attributes or should I use several attributes, e.g. let's say I've got a `Controller` class which reads several thermometers.

```
class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.temperature1 = Thermometer()
        self.temperature3 = Thermometer()
        self.temperature2 = Thermometer()
        self.temperature4 = Thermometer()
```

vs.

```
class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.temperature = tuple(Thermometer() for _ in range(4))
```

Is there a best practice when I should use which style?

(Let's assume the number of Thermometers will not be changed, otherwise choosing the second style with a list would be obvious.)

Comment: Is it possible to distinguish the different temperatures in any way? What makes temperature1 different from temperature3? I would try to find this distinction, use the first case and name the temperatures thereafter, such as temperatureInner, temperatureOuter and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tuple or list, 100%. `variable1`, `variable2`, etc... is a really common anti-pattern.

Think about how you code later - it's likely you'll want to do similar things to these items. In a data structure, you can loop over them to perform operations, with the numbered variable names, you'll have to do it manually. Not only that but it makes it easier to add in more values, it makes you code more generic and therefore more reusable, and means you can add new values mid-execution easily.

Why make the assumption the number will not be changed? More often than not, assumptions like that end up being wrong. Regardless, you can already see that the second example exemplifies the *do not repeat yourself* idiom that is central to clear, efficient code.

Even if you had more relevant names eg: `cpu_temperature`, `hdd_temperature`, I would say that if you ever see yourself performing the same operations on them, you want a data structure, not lots of variables. In this case, a dictionary:

```
temperatures = {
    "cpu": ...,
    "hdd": ...,
    ...
}
```

The main thing is that by storing the data in a data structure, you are giving the software the information about the grouping you are providing. If you just give them the variable names, you are only telling the programmer(s) - and if they are numbered, then you are not even really telling the programmer(s) what they are.

Comment: If positional access is of interest you may also want to have a look at [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) which are _"tuple-like objects that have fields accessible by attribute lookup as well as being indexable and iterable"_.

Comment: @PedroRomano An excellent point. If you use these tuples a lot across your program, ``namedtuple``s are an excellent alternative to a full-blown class.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to store them as a dictionary:

```
{1: temp1, 2: temp2}
```

The most important thing in deciding how to store data is relaying the data's *meaning*, if these items are essentially the same information in a slightly different context then they should be grouped (in terms of data-type) to relay that - i.e. they should be stored as either a tuple or a dictionary.

Note: if you use a tuple and then later insert more data, e.g. a `temp0` at the beginning, then there could be backwards-compatability issues where you've grabbed individual variables. (With a dictionary `temp[1]` will always return `temp1`.)

Comment: Why would there be *backwards-compatability issues* with a tuple?

Comment: @Lattyware if you insert `temp0` to make it `(temp0, temp1, temp2, ...)` rather than `(temp1, tempt2,...` (accessing the first element will no longer get temperature1).

Comment: Oh, so you are talking about each of the numbered temperatures needing completely disparate processing, and being accessed by index? I presumed that if the data was stored in a list/tuple, it would be iterated over (which would obviously be unaffected by adding new items), while a dictionary would be used if there was a need to do individual, separate processing, as per my answer.